# JS create property in a class which is the same type

Tags: javascript

I have a use case where I want to create a property in a class which is a new instance of the current class. For example:

```
class Test {

  constructor() {
    this.prop = new Test()
  }

}

const t = new Test();
```

The problem is that I get `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. There is any way to do it?

Comment: Well, each test is creating an internal test which is creating an internal test… How many objects do you want to create? Stop somewhere if you want to avoid the exception. Otherwise the code is fine, it does what you want.

Comment: I want to set it once

Comment: So the inner `Test` should not have this property? Should it have a different value, `undefined`? Pass an argument to tell it to do that.

Comment: No, it should not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the constructor is called again when you do `new Test()`, so you get an endless call of the constructor.

You probably should do this one by one, and call a method explicitly when you want to "deepen" the object structure with a next instance of `Test`, like so:

```
class Test {    
  constructor() {
    this.child = undefined;
  }
  createChild() {
    return this.child = new Test();
  }
}

const t = new Test();
const child = t.createChild();
const grandChild = child.createChild();
// ...etc
```

Now you control how deeply nested this structure should become. Maybe you just want one level deep? Then just call `createChild` only on the first instance.

Comment: The issue is that I need to call super(). There is a way to do it?

Comment: Sure, there is. What is the problem with it?

Comment: If I call super() I will still get an infinite loop.

Comment: Not unless you have some other code that is responsible for the looping. But your question was not about `super`, so is your question really about something else than what you actually asked? ;-)